# How to pass constructor arguments, to a NestJS provider?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have some Service, which requires a config object literal in its constructor, something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class BatteriesService { 

    constructor(private config: Config) { }//The provider needs a config object 

}
```

If I simply add this class in the providers array of the module, I obviously get an error, being that a constructor argument is missing.

So, instead of just referencing the BatteriesService class, I need to somehow create an instance. I tried this:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [BatteriesController],
  providers: [{
    useFactory: ()=>{
     return new BatteriesService({'someProp': 'someValue'})
    },
    provide:'BatteriesService'
  }]
})
```

And this:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [BatteriesController],
  providers: [{
    useValue:new BatteriesService({'someProp': 'someValue'}),
    provide:'BatteriesService'
  }]
})
```

In both cases I get the following error:

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BatteriesController (?).
> Please make sure that the argument BatteriesService at index [0] is
> available in the BatteriesModule context.

How can this done, without "resorting" to bypassing the DI system, or creating another "inner" provider(config)?

Answer (score 11):

When you need to have DI in service that has to be defined in the module.

In your case

```js
@Injectable()
export class BatteriesService { 
  constructor(private config: ConfigService) { }
}

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({})], // Configure it as needed
  providers: [BatteriesService]
})
```

Your mistake is that you don't actually import `ConfigModule` while your service is dependent on it.

If you wish to use `useFactory` method then it would look like

```js
@Module({
  providers: [{
    useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
      return new BatteriesService(config);
    },
    provide: BatteriesService,
    inject: [ConfigService]
  }]
})
```

I assumed your `Config` is actually Nest [ConfigModule](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration).

But if it's some custom Module you still need to import it as in the above examples.

If you want to pass an object literal as a config try this

```js
interface MyConfigType = {
  something: string;
}
@Injectable()
export class BatteriesService { 
  constructor(@Inject('CONFIG') private config: MyConfigType) { }
}

@Module({
  providers: [{
    provide: 'CONFIG',
    useValue: {
      something: 'my-value'
    }
  }]
})
```

Comment: Ah no, I don't have any config module, I just pass an object literal as config. Your approach is what I meant by "creating another "inner" provider", which seems like an overkill to me :D

Comment: Okay, added another example